# Cufon not working on javascript text

Tags: javascript, wordpress, cufon

I'm working on a wordpress theme and I'm changing the font menu with cufon.
It works fine except for the home button which is generated via javascript and I can not change it. I tried to target him in different ways but there is no way to turn it, even if i target it directly.

The script which I call the javascript function is this:

```
$ ('ul # menu-main-menu'). prepend ('<li id="#homepage"> <a href="homepage"> Home </ a> </ li>') ;
```

and that the cufon:

```
Cufon ('ul # menu-main-menu', {
     hover {color: '-linear-gradient (# aba197, 0.5 = # aba197, 0.8 = # 887d72, # 887d72)', textshadow: '-1px-1px # 000'},
  color: '-linear-gradient (# f5f2eb, 0.5 = # f5f2eb, 0.8 acaaa4 = #, # acaaa4)', textshadow: '-1px-1px # 000',
});
```

Can someone please help me understand why it does not work?

Comment: Slightly offtopic: How about webfonts? They just work nowadays. Not to mention some cool solutions like 'awesome font' for icons.

I also believe there is a cufon.now() function. Try to runing it after DOM operations.